# Sightseeing in a class Bravo airspace?

Tags: airspace, visual-flight-rules, class-b-airspace

I went to go fly around DFW today, wanted to do some sight see of the city and such. When I got in the air I contacted approach to get VFR flight following and was going to remain outside of the class B airspace anyways for most of it. When requesting to go closer I was told I would need to have an LOA with KDAL (Dallas-Lovefield), which I did not so I remained outside the Bravo, what is an LOA and or how is the best way to be inside the class B for sight seeing?

Comment: For the question in the title: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-do-i-sightsee-in-a-class-bravo-airspace?rq=1  (Doesn't help with your specific situation.)

Answer (score 4):

Letters of Authorization (LOAs) are authorization to conduct various types of commercial flights in certain airspace.  They are defined and governed by [FAA Order 8900.1](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICResults.aspx?mode=EBookContents&restricttocategory=all~menu) and can be obtained from the regional Flight Standards District Office (FSDO) for that area.  It is not necessary for non-commercial general aviation operations.  I suspect (and I don't know the full details as to how you contacted Ft Worth Approach) that the controller thought you were a commercial operation requesting to start doing some sightseeing over the Dallas Ft. Worth Area without having done this paperwork.

Usually as a GA pilot, you can simply contact approach control for a Class B airspace and request a transition through Class Bravo.  This request may or may not be granted depending on commercial traffic congestion that day, etc.  They may also want you to stick to existing VFR traffic transition routes and not deviate from that.  Class B, as a general rule, is not very accommodating for sightseeing and other leisure flying.

Comment: Thank you where can I find the VFR traffic transitions? And can a GA pilot option an LOA so they are able to conduct these types of operations.

Comment: @iqueqiorio, if you don't know how to get a clearance I would suggest you get some instructor time on the ground to go over it. You want to make sure you get it right or you could lose your ticket.

Comment: VFR transition routes are listed on the backs of terminal area charts, if they are published, or check the chart supplements for that region.

Comment: Most TRACONs have canned "tours" you can request; ask a local CFI/FBO or phone TRACON yourself for a list. They might approve *minor* deviations in the air, depending on traffic, but it's unlikely they'll approve anything novel.